# Acquiring an ID from a newly inserted entry in an MSSQL database

Tags: c#, sql

In an MSSQL database, I have automatically increasing IDs for every entry. 
Is it safe to acquire the ID of the newly inserted entry like this? I am worried that, if at the exact same time another entry gets inserted, I could end up with the wrong ID.

```
string query = "INSERT INTO subscriptions (polygon,...) VALUES (@polygon,...)";
                    SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter();  
                    using (SqlCommand querySaveSubscription = new SqlCommand(query))
                    {
                        querySaveSubscription.Connection = openCon;
                        // Create Poly out of given geodata values
                        var point = SqlGeography.Point(Double.Parse(lat), Double.Parse(lon), 4326);
                        SqlGeography poly = point.BufferWithTolerance(Double.Parse(radius) * 1000, 0.01, true);



                        var param = new SqlParameter(@"polygon", poly);
                        param.UdtTypeName = "Geography";

                        querySaveSubscription.Parameters.Add(param);
        ...



                        openCon.Open();
                        querySaveSubscription.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have the following c# code directly after my INSERT INTO - query getting executed:

```
                    query = "SELECT ID FROM subscriptions ORDER BY ID DESC";
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, openCon);
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    reader.Read();

                    int id = reader.GetInt32(0);

                    result.Add("success", "true");

                    result.Add("id", id.ToString());
```

Comment: No, it's not safe ;) You need to use SCOPE_IDENTITY when you insert your row and return that from your insert query. If you post the insert code as well you might get a full review.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - if you want provide details in an answer so i can vote / accept you

Comment: Would love to but I've been waiting five minutes for my wife for a while now so don't think I have time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `scope_identity` [as @RobH hinted in a comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87336/acquiring-an-id-from-a-newly-inserted-entry-in-an-mssql-database#comment157789_87336), but the sexiest way IMO is to use [the `OUTPUT` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) of the `INSERT` syntax:

```sql
DECLARE @result TABLE (Id INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO subscriptions (polygon,...) 
VALUES (@polygon,...)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @result;

SELECT Id FROM @result;
```

Now, having a whole multi-statement `CommandText` like this, even if it's parameterized, isn't desirable at all, and makes for pretty ugly C# code - why not put that T-SQL in a stored procedure, and call that instead?

Speaking of parameters, your code snippet, as small as it is, is showing us that your method is breaking SRP (Single Responsibility Principle):

> ```
>    // Create Poly out of given geodata values
>     var point = SqlGeography.Point(Double.Parse(lat), Double.Parse(lon), 4326);
>     SqlGeography poly = point.BufferWithTolerance(Double.Parse(radius) * 1000, 0.01, true);
> ```

That logic doesn't belong there at all: you need a `SqlGeography`-type parameter, fine. That doesn't mean the logic for translating `lat` and `lon` values into one belongs in that method.

Side note, I get what `lat` and `lon` stand for *in the context of creating a `SqlGeography` value*, but these are bad variable names nonetheless: there's no reason to shorten the names like this - not even "it's faster to type"; with IntelliSense you type "lat" and it autocompletes "latitude" for you.

---

I'm going to make a little assumption here. This makes me think your method is returning something like a `Dictionary<string,string>`:

> ```
> result.Add("success", "true");
> result.Add("id", id.ToString());
> ```

That's a very error-prone way of working. The `"success"` value is useless, because *if you have a value, you have a successful insert*. If you *don't* have a value, you're dealing with an exception - and I see no `try/catch` block in your code, so I'm hoping the caller is handling such an exception...

You could have a class somewhere, with properties for each column of a database table / entity you're working with, and you should return that instead... but the simplest return type to use would be a `Nullable<int>`, so that the method either succeeded and returns the `Id` for the inserted record, or failed and returns `null` - for that to happen reliably, you'll need to wrap your logic in a `try/catch` block, and handle any `SqlException` that might be thrown in the process.

---

Another thing is that you're not properly disposing of your connection there. `SqlConnection` implements `IDisposable`, and the instance should be wrapped in a `using` block, too. Also I would try to open the connection *before* I start creating the command, so that I could pass the connection into the command's constructor (and not even bother instantiating it if the connection can't be opened). Keeps things cleaner I find:

```
try
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
catch (SqlException)
{
    return null;
}
```

---

Lastly, I find that you're using confusing identifiers: in the top snippet your `adapter` is called `cmd`, and your `command` is called `querySaveSubscription`, as if it were a string containing the SQL statement (and the SQL string in question is called `query`... but doesn't *query* anything). ...but then in the bottom snippet a command is called a `command` and a reader is called a `reader`, and a connection that might never have successfully opened is called `openCon`. Would you ever work with a `closedCon`? Why not just call it `connection` then?

Comment: A really elegant solution. You put a lot of effort in your answer, thanks man!

Comment: Eh, this is *Code Review*, welcome aboard! :)